# python-ldap coudl't be installed

Tags: python, c, windows, openldap, python-ldap

I'm trying to install python-ldap, but this raise an error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.4.4 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules "-IC:\Users\eramirez\Desktop\event manager\venv\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
      LDAPObject.c
      C:\Users\eramirez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p14kzml2\python-ldap_e1867abcc3f14889836862942949d730\Modules\common.h(15): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'lber.h': No such file or directory 
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have installed vscode 2019 and 2022 because some answers for there said I have to install a C compiler, but it throw error still, is there any solution for this problem. Another library to use or tell me what I am doing wrong ....

Please, I feel a little stressed, thank you very much too.

Comment: Searching around [starting here](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.3/installing.html#windows) I found this [unofficial repo building the wheel for windows](https://github.com/cgohlke/python-ldap-build/). Maybe try that instead of [building it yourself](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.3/installing.html#build-prerequisites).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27lber.h%27+No+such+file+or+directory -- just search for the error message.